# Motors not rotating despite correct PWM Signal coming from Pixhawk

Tags: pwm, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, motordriver, drone

We are working on an autonomous Quadrocopter powered by an NVIDIA Jetson Xavier NX as the central control computer and the Pixhawk 6X as Flight Controller. The commands are being sent from the Jetson to the Pixhawk via MAVLINK. The PWM Signals coming from FMU OUT are correct (measured by Oscilloscope), however, the motors are not spinning at all, and the 3 Motor Phases only reach a max voltage of 1 V. We are using a T-Motor F60A 4 in 1 ESC. The Pixhawk is powered via USB from the Jetson, as well as the Data Transmission.
One thing that could be is that F_PWM only has 50 Hz, which might need some adjustments.
Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks in advance!